# append row in data frame from existing data frame row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with Id, Ids Neighbours, and their centres.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, '[2,3,5]','c0'], [2, '[3,5]','c1'], [3, '[2]','c2'],[4, '[5]','c1'],[5, 
'[1,2]','c2']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Id', 'Neighbors',"Center"])
df
```

Now I need to reassigned the centre values based on each neighbours for each Id.

My expected output is

```
Id    Neighbors    Center
1     [2,3,5]       c0
2     [3,5]         c1
3     [2]           c2
4     [5]           c1
5     [1,2]         c2
1     [2,3,5]       c1
1     [2,3,5]       c2
1     [2,3,5]       c2   
2     [3,5]         c2
2     [3,5]         c2
3     [2]           c1
4     [5]           c2
5     [1,2]         c0
5     [1,2]         c1
```

Suppose, the neighbours of Id 1 are 2,3, and 5. Now I need to append new row and assigned the centres of Id 2, 3, and 5 with Id 1 values.

Comment: It looks you you are just copy the values over and over... care to explain the logic?

Comment: This question was just closed and got multiple downvotes, so you decided to just post it again pretty much identical? Maybe you should think about why that happened. Don't want to be harsh but why do you think you'll get help now? Please have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site.

Comment: You seem to have duplicate rows in your desired output. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of like **graph** stuff,
need to figure out the parent-child relationship, `Id` is parent's level, `Neighbors` is child level, and the target is to find the children's `Center` with the original parent's Info and concatenate back to them.

```
df['Neighbors'] = df['Neighbors'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
df_exp = df.explode('Neighbors')
df_merged = df_exp.merge(df_exp[['Id','Center']], left_on='Neighbors', right_on='Id', suffixes=('_left', '_right')).drop_duplicates().sort_values('Id_left')
df_merged['Neighbors'] = df_merged['Id_left'].map(df.set_index('Id')['Neighbors'])
df_merged.drop(columns=['Center_left', 'Id_right'], inplace=True)
df_merged.rename(columns={'Id_left':'Id', 'Center_right':'Center'}, inplace=True)
output = pd.concat([df, df_merged], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
output
###
    Id  Neighbors Center
0    1  [2, 3, 5]     c0
1    2     [3, 5]     c1
2    3        [2]     c2
3    4        [5]     c1
4    5     [1, 2]     c2
5    1  [2, 3, 5]     c1
6    1  [2, 3, 5]     c2
7    1  [2, 3, 5]     c2
8    2     [3, 5]     c2
9    2     [3, 5]     c2
10   3        [2]     c1
11   4        [5]     c2
12   5     [1, 2]     c1
13   5     [1, 2]     c0
```

This kind of structure is not rare, in property declaration from the Ministry of Finance, this is a way to connect the wealth of families, e.g., `Id` could be the parent's Id, `Neighbors` could be the child's Id, and `Center` could be a file name of property inventory.